# Hibernate relationship @ManyToMany using @OneToMany&@ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm working JPA and Hibernate for this quarter's final. I am having a infinit loop. I tried to use @ManyToMany but the teacher doesn`t want us to use it. So I used this.

Here is the first entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Routes")
public class Routes {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id_route")
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private Airport origin;

@OneToOne
private Airport destination;

@Column(name = "distance")
private float distance;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "route")
private List<RouteXCabin> cabinas= new ArrayList<>();
```

The second one,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cabins")
public class Cabin {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id_cabin")
private int id;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "name")
private String nombre;
```

And finally the join entity/table

```
@Table(name = "routes_x_cabins")
public class RouteXCabin {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_Rxc")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_route")
private Routes route;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_cabin")
private Cabin cabin;
```

And i'm having this loop [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8x59.png).
Any idea of how to solve this? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'i'm having this loop'? The association is bidirectional, what else did you expect to get? I can't see anything that needs solving

Comment: I could not convert the answer to a json that was the problem. I resolve that using a DTO. @crizzis

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "route")
private List<RouteXCabin> cabinas= new ArrayList<>();


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_route")
private Routes route;
```

You get infinite loop because you set eager fetch type for both of them. You should set at least one of them with lazy fetch type. In fact, you can delete fetch types because default fetch type of OneToMany is lazy and ManyToOne is eager.